# Atomicity of Reads and Writes for Variables in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

this is a followup on another [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774010/atomicity-of-reads-and-writes-for-reference-variables-in-java/42723149#42723149).

@templatetypedef answered the question (appreciated), and in his answer he wrote:

> As a note - atomicity does not mean "all other threads will be blocked
>   until the value is ready. It means all other threads will either see
>   the state purely before the operation is done or purely after the
>   operation is done, but nothing else.

I have a confusion regarding this, and here’s why:

It says [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

> Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear
>   of thread interference.

What I infer from this, is that it contradicts what he wrote.

If we have 2 int variables i1 and i2, and we do the atomic operation `i1=i2;` and this operation is executed by threadX.

Then if atomic actions cannot be interleaved as indicated above, it means that during this atomic operation (executed by threadX), no other threadY is allowed to access (for either read or write) that same variable i2, hence, no other threadY, is allowed to access that same variable during the atomic operation, so some form of blocking does exist.

Did I get this right?

Thanks...

Comment: No, it means that threadY will either see *all* of the assignment, or *none* of the assignment... it won't see "a few bits of i2, and a few bits of the previous value of i1".

Comment: @Jon Skeet, so if what u say is true, then this quote: "Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference." is flase, because during the atomic operation i1=i2, threadX and threadY might interleave on the same data (i2 in this case). I get your point of threadY will always read the value before the atomic operation or after, but if threadY is allowed to read i2 during the atomic operation i1=i2; then threadX and threadY interleave on i2, but that according to Oracle tutorial is not possible, am I missing something?

Comment: *Reading* i2 (or, often, a separate copy of i2 from a different CPU cache) in a different thread can't constitute interleaving, since there's no observable difference even if it happens at the same wall-clock time. *Writing* i2 in a different thread at the same wall-clock time doesn't constitute interleaving iff the end result is as if "i1=i2" got either the full old or the full new i2 value, since it's consistent with behavior that the other thread did actions either before or after "i1=i2", so that's not interleaving in the middle of an atomic action, it just results in a different ordering.

Comment: The quote about "...can be used without fear of thread interference..." does not tell the whole story.  When we talk about "thread safety", we have to talk about it at every layer of the architecture.  Reads and writes to an `int` variable are thread safe for reasons already discussed here, but that does _not_ automatically make your algorithm that uses int variables thread safe.  And, if you take the necessary steps to insure the safety of your algorithm, that does not insure the safety of code that calls your algorithm, and so on, up the stack.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge there is no atomic `i1 = i2` operation. You can atomically read an int and you can atomically write to one, but you can't do both in the same operation with synchronization. So `i1 = i2` is two different atomic operations, a read followed by a write. You are guaranteed that nothing will interleave the read operation so you won't see partial updates to `i2` when you read it, and you are guaranteed that nothing will interleave the write to `i1`, but there's no guarantee that nothing will happen in between those two atomic operations.

Lets say Thread t1 is going to do:

```
i2 = 10
i1 = i2
```

And thread t2 is going to do:

```
i1 = 7
i2 = 18
System.out.println(i1)
```

What you are guaranteed is that t1 will end up assigning either 10 or 18 to i1 but you can't know which. However, you are guaranteed it can't be any other value because the read of i2 and the write to i1 are atomic so you can't end up seeing some of the bits of i2 while it's being modified. Similarly, t2 is guaranteed to print either 10, 18, or 7 and it can't print anything else. However, without synchronization there's no way to know which of those 3 values it will end up printing.

Answer (score 1):

> ... it means that during this atomic operation (executed by threadX), no other threadY is allowed to access (for either read or write) that same variable i2, hence, no other threadY, is allowed to access that same variable during the atomic operation, so some form of blocking does exist.

No you didn't get it right.

Atomic operations mean that threads can not see values in a *partial* state.  The assignment is atomic depending on the underlying architecture running your JVM and the data size of `i1` and `i2`.  I believe that Java says that `int` fields are atomically assigned but `long` (and `double`) may not be because it may take multiple operations by the CPU.

> Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference.

This is right.  If `i1` is 1 and `i2` is 2 and `threadX` executes the assignment, then any other thread will either see the value of `i1` as 1 (the old value) or 2 (the new value).  `ThreadY` won't see it be some sort of half-way between 1 or 2 because that assignment is atomic even if multiple threads are updating the value of `i1`.

But what is really confusing the matter is that there are two concepts going on here: atomicity and memory synchronization.  With threads, each CPU has its own memory cache so that memory operations are first made to the local memory and then these changes are written to main memory.  A thread might see an old copy of `i1` in its local cached memory even though another thread has updated main memory already.  Even worse is when two threads have updated the value of `i1` in their local memory and depending on their order of operations (which is highly random) one thread's value will overwrite the other thread's write to main memory.  It's extremely hard to know which one will win the [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550/179850).

> As a note - atomicity does not mean "all other threads will be blocked until the value is ready.

Right.  This is trying to let you know that there is no locking involved at all here.  There are no guarantees as to the value that `ThreadY` will see.  `ThreadY` could also be updating `i1` at the same exact time to the value 3 and then other threads could see it as 1, 2, or 3 depending on the order of operations and whether or not those threads cross [memory barriers](https://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) when the cache flushing and updating is enforced.

The way we control fields and objects that are shared between threads is with the `synchronized` keyword, which gives a thread unique access to a resource.  There are also `Lock`s and other mechanisms to provide mutex.  We also can force memory barriers by adding a `volatile` keyword to a field which means that any read or write to the field will be made to main memory.  Both `synchronized` and `volatile` ensure proper publishing of data and ordering of operations.